# Get value return of apollo.fetch in Swift IOS (Apollo Client)

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, closures, apollo

I've on my app Apollo client to make request GraphQL to an API.
I want put my requests in a class like that:

```
 class requestAPI {
  static func checkUsername(nameUser: String!) -> Bool{
    var res: Bool = false
    Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: CheckUsernameQuery(username: nameUser)) { result in
      switch result {
        case .success(let response):
          res = response.data?.checkUsername
          print(“Reponse: \(response.data?.checkUsername)“)
        case .failure(let error):
          print(“Error: \(error)“)
      }
    }
    return res
  }
}
```

So i just want to get value response.data.checkUsername and return it, but res is always false because i think that the fetch is asynch.
So what can i do to get the value of response.data.checkUsername (it's a Bool) and return it ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-posting from the [Apollo Spectrum Chat](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-ios/get-value-return-of-apollo-fetch-in-swift-ios-apollo-client~6ed5ac06-4a18-4049-8b73-481950fe3485):

Hi! You'll need to use a completion closure like this:

```swift
static func checkUsername(nameUser: String!, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
  Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: CheckUsernameQuery(username: nameUser)) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
      res = response.data?.checkUsername ?? false
      completion(res)
    case .failure(let error):
      // whatever error handling you want to do
  }
}
```

The closure is a function that you pass as a parameter, and then you call it with the result asynchronously rather than returning the result directly from the function.

This is a pretty common pattern in Swift - I'd recommend reading up on it. The [Swift doc on closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) is exceptionally long and probably a little too detailed as a starting point, but it covers a *ton* of stuff. I think a better intro-level piece is [John Sundell's article about closures](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/closures/).